# MFC: Prevent CDialog from being hidden when main window is minimized?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a derived CDialog (actually CBCGPDialog) that was created with a NULL parent window.   Yet, when I minimize the main program the dialog goes away.   If I do something like:

```
void CMyDlg::OnShowWindow(BOOL bShow, UINT nStatus)
{
  CBCGPDialog::OnShowWindow(bShow, nStatus);
  
  if (bShow==0 && nStatus==SW_PARENTCLOSING) {
    ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  }
}
```

It will open it back up but there is a flash.   Where would I catch the minimize request in `CMyDlg` to prevent it from minimizing?  (This dialog only has a close option on it, so if they don't want it shown, they would close it, it contains more of a window to show stuff than a normal dialog of options,  maybe I should move it to a `CWnd`?)

Comment: Look for [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanging).

Comment: Would I be looking at `SWP_HIDEWINDOW`?  If so, where do I tell if it's coming because the parent is being minimized (because there are times the program itself will hide it and should hide)?  or do I have to track myself? If so, what is the guaranteed order of the messages?

Comment: Since you are passing `NULL` for the owner window, do you actually want to create an unowned dialog?

Comment: I made it NULL to keep as a separate window and both can be used at the same time and keep it from minimizing as a child.

Comment: @user3161924 If you clear the `SWP_HIDEWINDOW` bit, then dialog will not be hidden. You'll have to keep track of the state of the app in order to decide when to do that. At the time `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` is received, the main window is still fully visible, and you can't tell whether it's in the process of being minimized vs. displaying/operating normally.

Comment: Okay, thanks, moving over from `CDialog` to `CWnd` doesn't have the problem, so I'll just make the test of using `CWnd` permanent.

Comment: Passing `NULL` for `pParentWnd` in a call to [CDialog::Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class#create) has a different effect: *"If `pParentWnd` is `NULL`, the dialog box will be created with its parent or owner window set to the main application window."*